# How do I add a multi select combo box to my ASP.net webform in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, ajax, forms, visual-studio

Im trying to add a multi select combo box control to my asp.net webform in Visual Studio 2010.

How can I go about doing this? are there any AJAX entenders for this?

Appreciated
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a simple `<select>` element with `multiple` attribute set?

```
<select id="cmbElement" multiple>
    <option value="1">First value</option>
    <option value="2">Second value</option>
    <option value="3">Third value</option>
</select>
```

In ASP.Net you can use a **[`ListBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx)** and then set  **[`ListBox.SelectionMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.selectionmode.aspx)** property  to `Multiple`

```
 <asp:ListBox id="ListBox1" Rows="6" Width="100px" SelectionMode="Multiple"  runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul! I am trying to get away from using control or shift to select multiple entries in the combo box.